# Shared validation error message for more than one field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

In an ASP.NET MVC project I'm trying to validate several fields against a regular expression. However I would like to have only one validation message displayed if any of them fails (and highlight the ones failing).

I can make a custom validation for that, and annotating one of them with the id's of the rest kind of work although only highlights the one decorated with the attribute. But it looks to me as an overkill as I just want to reduce the message to one.

In the same form I will try to do the same for two checkboxes, both must be checked.

So as far as I understand if I use the summary to put a generic message won't be able to tell if it's failing for the checkboxes or for the fields.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom validation that targets your entire view model class. I wrote the following when I wanted to check that at least one property was set. You can see that this targets the class itself and should therefore give you one message.

```
/// <summary>
/// A configurable class wide attribute that is used to determine if at least one property of a class has received a value.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SingleValueConfigurableAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public SingleValueConfigurableAttribute(string errorKey)
    { ErrorMessage = Properties.Settings.Default[errorKey].ToString(); }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var typeInfo = value.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = typeInfo.GetProperties();

        return propertyInfo.Any(property => null != property.GetValue(value, null));
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage) ? FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName) : ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "enforcetrue"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidHirst I'm trying to wire it with the jquery validation and will update